# Определить время, затраченное на запрос. Java

Tags: java, база-данных, запрос

Есть некая таблица с данными о работниках. SLQ запрос выводит данные об определенных работниках. Нужно написать программу, определяющую время, затраченное на запрос.

Comment: покажите код, который делает запрос в базу

Comment: SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES

Comment: Опишите вашу проблему конкретней. Время, затраченное на запрос, это промежуток времни между отправкой запроса и получением его результата. Какую программу вы собираетесь для этого написать?

Answer (score 1):

```
long starttime = System.nanoTime();
// Выполнение запроса ...
long finishtime = System.nanoTime();
long timeConsumedMillis = finishtime - starttime;
```

Comment: consumedNanos тогда уж

Comment: не буду спорить, но добавлю, что я бы использовал System.currentTimeMillis(), как менее жрущий ресурсы ПК, если не требуется особая точность рассчётов.